# How to send file path to passport.js local-signup for a file image

Tags: javascript, passport.js, multer

Just as a heads up I'm learning to build applications using NodeJS, Express, MongoDB. I'm working on a particular web app that has the user upload a file. I have successfully used multer to save a file to an uploads folder. (Right now I'm assuming it is saving correctly because the form doesn't throw an error on submit and the uploads folder has a file with the input name and current date). I'm using passport.js to register new users and authenticate existing users. So I need to send this file path into the passport.authenticate(local-signup,{/*Success & Errors in here*/} so that when it creates the new user in my database it has this information that I can use on the profile page to display the image they uploaded. Below is the necessary folder structure(not all but what is involved) and the routes, models(for db) and passport.js file. The passport documentation looked like the only other thing you can send with passport.authenticate is the session object so I'm not sure how to achieve this. Can anyone explain how it is commonly done?

Folder Structure

```
myapp
  -config
    -passport.js
  -models
    -user.js
  -public
  -routes
    -index.js
  -uploads
    -stateID-09202016
  -views
    -signup.ejs
    -profile.ejs
```

index.js(./routes/index.js)

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
  }
})
var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/signup', function(req, res) {  
  res.render('signup.ejs', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') });
})
    .post('/signup', upload.single('stateID'), passport.authenticate('local-    signup', {  
      successRedirect: '/profile',
      failureRedirect: '/signup',
      failureFlash: true,
    }));

  module.exports = router;

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {  
  if (req.isAuthenticated())
      return next();
  res.redirect('/');
}
```

user.js(./models/user.js)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    local:{
        email: String,
        password: String,
        firstName: String,
        mInitial: String,
        lastName: String,
        phoneNumber: String,
        cpassword: String,
        stateID: String
    },
});

userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {  
  return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};
userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {  
  return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password);
};
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

passport.js(./config/passport.js)

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;  
var User = require('../models/user');
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function(passport) {  
  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });
  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });

  passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true,
  },
  function(req, email, password, done) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
      User.findOne({ 'local.email':  email }, function(err, user) {
        if (err)
            return done(err);
        if (user) {
          return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already in use.'));
        } else {
          var newUser = new User();
          newUser.local.email = email;
          newUser.local.firstName = req.body.firstName;
          newUser.local.mInitial = req.body.mInitial;
          newUser.local.lastName = req.body.lastName;
          newUser.local.phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber;
          newUser.local.cpassword = req.body.cpassword;
          newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);
          newUser.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
              throw err;
            return done(null, newUser);
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }));
  /*Not showing passport.use(local-login) to save space*/
};
```